# Developement Environment for Spring MVC , Tomcat, and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, spring-mvc, development-environment

I am looking for some cloud services / free services which will allow me to setup the development environment for Spring, Tomcat , MySql.

We want the environment so that 3 to 4 developer can code on different parts of the application.

Any help will be appreciated..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Heroku](https://heroku.com). There even is a [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-spring-mvc-hibernate) how to configure Spring project. But Heroku uses Postgres for deployed app (if you don't have your own configure DB server). If MySql is not critical for you there is [free dev plan](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans#starter-tier) for Postres on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine might be what you're looking for. You've got free quotas and up to 10 apps (dev, qa, etc.). Of course, you need to use their high replication datastore (mysql instances are not free) but you can get your head around it and get a quite similar experience plus you get the benefits of a free dev environment, google scalability, etc.